# Lock error when converting polygon to raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, arcgis-10.5

I'm trying to convert a polygon file to raster but when I execute the function I get this error message:

> clement\cdq\landuse_mrc4. May be locked by another application. Failed to execute (polygonToRaster).

I've tried closing everything and doing it again but it still doesn't work... does anyone know what to do in this situation ?

Comment: Is the data on a shared drive? Is it possible someone else may be using the data at the same time?

Comment: If that is the error message they really need to improve their basic English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lock commonly means that another application is accessing a database, and the ability to alter its structure, such as by adding or removing fields, is restricted. A common cause for a schema lock is displaying a dataset while trying to modify the dataset in another application.

Solution - If using multiple applications, check whether those applications might be accessing the same data.

I usually get locks when:
 - someone else is using the data
 - I have multiple programs looking at the data
 - the data is in my mxd multiple times
 - the data is being used in a service and the service hasn't been shut down

You can try looking at your database connections to identify where the multiple connections are coming from, and either disconnect them from there, or manually shut things down.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still experiencing this you can export your map as a map package and then use the polygon to raster tool as a work around.